# If I specify a wildcard DNS entry, will it override any specific values?

Tags: dns

I have

```
cheese.mycompany.com - 1.1.1.1
```

I want to go

```
*.mycompany.com = 1.1.1.2
```

without effecting cheese? Will this work, just having two seprate DNS entries?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The wildcard does not override any specific values.   It acts as a catch-all.  **If there is no otherwise specified record**, the wildcard record gets used.

You can have both cheese.mycompany.com pointing at an ip address and a wildcard for everything else.

I do this on my site.  I use both A records for specific IP addresses for subdomains, and a catch-all wildcard.  They are completely compatible.